# Why do text and csv files act unpredictably when reading, in c++?

Tags: csv, c++11, text, ubuntu-18.04, readfile

I am using c++ and I have to process txt/csv files. Lines are basically records and fields are separated with commas. First I read the file and store it as myPoints and then call functions for calculating the modes of each field and finally the mode for each chunk of the data.
It works fine and I am pretty sure that the algorithm is working correctly, but the problem is that it doesn't treat same files in the same manner i.e. when storing each record in myPoints, sometimes it reads the last field with one extra character and if I cut and paste the same data in the same file, sometimes the problem is resolved and sometimes not.

I really don't know what is wrong here and that's why I can't fix it. This extra character causes me a lot of troubles as I can't calculate the modes correctly.

Any insights?

The code below is a part of an MPI project and each process is reading its right chunk of data from the same file here, plus as you can see I am using ifstream and stringstream to read and process the file:

```
unordered_map < int , unordered_map <int , vector<string> > > storeMyShareOfLines(string fileName , int rank , int numPointsLocal){

    string line;
    ifstream myfile(fileName,ios::in);

    vector<string> point;
    unordered_map < int , unordered_map <int , vector<string> > > myPoints;

    int start_line = rank * numPointsLocal;
    int end_line = start_line + numPointsLocal;
    

    if(!myfile.is_open()){
        cout<<"Failed to open"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    
    int j = 0;
    int myShare = 0;
    int line_counter = 0; 

    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
       
        if( myShare <= numPointsLocal)
        {
            if(start_line <= line_counter && line_counter < end_line)
            {
                myShare++;
                stringstream sline(line);
                string word;
                while (getline(sline , word , ','))
                {
                    point.push_back(word);
                }
                myPoints[rank][j] = point;
                j++;
                point.clear();
                line_counter++;

            }
            else
            {
    
                line_counter++;

            }
         
        }
        else
        {
            
            return myPoints;
            myfile.close();
        }
            

    }//While
    
}
```

Comment: time to debug your application

Comment: `getline(myfile, dataLine)` reads a whole-line into the string `dataLine`, but doesn't add the newline character at the end. Then you put this line into a `stringstream` and do `getline(sline, line2, '\n')` which makes no sense, since there's no newline in the string stream.

Comment: Also, CSV files are a *deceptively* simple file-format. There are many pitfalls and corner cases, not counting formatting errors in the file itself. There are many libraries available to read and parse CSV files, I suggest you try to find one of them and use instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So how can I read a file and process it correctly based on '\n' and ',' ? what's the correct way to do so?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and what library would you suggest ?

Comment: The way you currently does it, `sline` will contain a single "record" from the input file. Split it at comma and you have the separate data. I suggest you follow [the single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) and create more functions, like for example one function which takes a string and splits it into a `std::vector<std::string>` using an arbitrary character delimiter. It's a simple `std::getline` loop (with an `std::istringstream`). Then you an easily fetch the data fields using plain vector indexing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you very much for your comment and the idea. I will try to do that and hope it'll solve the problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : I modified the code as you suggested.(regarding '\n' character) but unfortunately it still shows one extra character for the last field. You can see my changes in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that if I open csv files with "LibreOffice/Excel" and manually delete some empty columns right after the last column of data I have, it'll solve the problem. I still don't know the exact reason behind the scenes though.

Hope it helps anyone with the same problem.